# Titles showing up with Numeric Codes

Tags: php

So currently my titles are showing up looking something like this.

`Z Ft. Fetty Wap - Nobody&#8217;s Better (CDQ)` instead of looking like this  *Z Ft. Fetty Wap - Nobody’s Better (CDQ)*.

How can I fix this? I am currently using WordPress and exploding the standard `the_title` function into something that looks like this.

```
$title = htmlentities(get_the_title ());

$str = explode ("&amp;#8211;", $title);

$artist = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[0]);

$song = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[1]);
```

this way I am able to get both parts the artist name and the song name and use them where I feel fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `htmlspecialchars_decode()`

You can see an example [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)